# Cambiar User Agent PHP

Tags: php

I am making requests in PHP to a server repeatedly and I would like to know how I can make that each time it requests a request it is a user agent different from the previous request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `curl` to perform the request in PHP, you can change the user agent as so (assuming `$ch` is your curl handle):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User Agent 123');
```

Simply change `'User Agent 123'` to your chosen user agent and this will be sent with the request when executed.

Using `curl_setopt` allows you to change many aspects of the curl request.  This is detailed in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). With regards to `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` specifically, the docs state:

> The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP
> request.

Which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

**Alternative Method Using `ini_set`**

There is an alternative way to change the default user agent used by PHP using the configuration setting `user_agent`.  This can be set using `ini_set` as so:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'My User Agent 123');
```

The documentation about this is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent). Specifically regarding `user_agent`:

> Define the user agent for PHP to send.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you tell me a website where all the types of user-agent are?

Comment: @MiguelRodriguezGarcia You're welcome. There are lots of sites that list various user agents - one I have used is https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/

Comment: Thank you very much but I am currently using simpledom is there any way to do the same as before?

Comment: @MiguelRodriguezGarcia Perhaps you should have mentioned that in your question! Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393664/user-agent-in-php-simple-html-dom-parser